# xcode highlight issues

Tags: xcode

I have been working on a project with Xcode 3.2.6 for a few months (first time with Xcode). I really liked the following feature:

when I searched for the occurrence of a term, say 'house', Xcode highlighted ALL the occurrences of 'house' in the file that I am looking at. Moreover, it used to tell me how many occurrences there were. If I decided to replace ALL the 'houses' for 'home' say, it will tell me how many replacements it did.

A week ago I initialized Xcode and was doing something else at the same time, so some message (which I couldn't read) appeared and apparently I screw up this configuration. Now the find tool will highlight only the FIRST occurrence of a word, and the replace ALL feature doesn't tell me how many occurrences I am replacing.

This might sound dumb but I really want this back, it is very useful for me.

I tried everything that I could think of but I haven't been able to figure out how to revert it.

I know I could just reset Xcode to the defaults but I don't want to do that because I have changed (not now, at the beginning) many other features.

Any help will be really appreciated!!!!!

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete all derived data in the XCode folder and the restart!

Comment: Hey Johan, thanks for your answer. but... how do I delete the derived data? how do I find the Xcode folder? thank you and sorry about the stupid questions...

Comment: You might have to show enable show hidden files.

Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
is the usual path

Comment: Hi Johan, I think that this solution applies for Xcode 4, but I am using Xcode 3, so I don't see this DerivedData Folder, even if I show hidden files. Any other ideas??? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Delete Derived Data in Organizer under Projects option，then restart xCode